# How can I read this crash log from Apple

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, crash-reports

I just had my app reviewed by Apple and it apparently crashed, which I cannot reproduce (same device and iOS version).

The app crashed when they clicked on a button which
1. Shows a new view with a modal segue
2. Accesses address book

I've been looking at the two crashlogs they sent me but I'm stuck, while it doesn't look very complicated.

Could you help me and guide me through it?

Thanks a lot!

I renamed my app MyGreatApp in the log, and just pasted the part about the thread that crashed, if you need anything else, please ask !

**Edit:** I symbolicated the log thanks to @Larme , pretty self explanatory now :)

So does this mean it could not instantiate the view from storyboard? the `obj_exception throw` means that the controller does not exist? Because it works fine on my device…

```
    {"bundleID":"com.mygreatcompany.MyGreatApp","app_name":"MyGreatApp","bug_type":"109","name":"MyGreatApp","os_version":"iPhone OS 7.1.2 (11D257)","version":"1.0 (1.0)"}
Incident Identifier: 4566AD36-97C0-4064-9A4B-8A73312D8201
CrashReporter Key:   ca6a56d3ed180cf7e13810af8336141d041a0ab1
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             MyGreatApp [3158]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/81C2C8B9-8CA5-4F5A-8E1F-BFEA4A6F81B3/MyGreatApp.app/MyGreatApp
Identifier:          com.mygreatcompany.MyGreatApp
Version:             1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-08-18 12:16:59.806 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.2 (11D257)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x182c4b100 __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x18f6281fc objc_exception_throw + 60
2   UIKit                           0x186156188 -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:] + 528
3   MyGreatApp                      0x100022d60 +[User addFriendsWithContactsAndViewController:] (User.m:113)
4   MyGreatApp                      0x10003d8cc -[SendEventViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] (SendEventViewController.m:310)
5   UIKit                           0x185d45780 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1264
6   UIKit                           0x185e0621c -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 240
7   UIKit                           0x185c9a458 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 356
8   UIKit                           0x185c0648c _afterCACommitHandler + 504
9   CoreFoundation                  0x182c0b858 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
10  CoreFoundation                  0x182c08ae0 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
11  CoreFoundation                  0x182c08e6c __CFRunLoopRun + 764
12  CoreFoundation                  0x182b49dd0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
13  GraphicsServices                0x1887e9c0c GSEventRunModal + 168
14  UIKit                           0x185c7afc4 UIApplicationMain + 1156
15  MyGreatApp                      0x10003ed68 main (main.m:16)
16  libdyld.dylib                   0x18fc1baa0 start + 4
```

Comment: @Larme looking into it, didn't know about it, I'm pretty new to this :)

Comment: Thanks @Larme i've symbolicated the crash log
Still not sure why it is working on my device though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After symbolicating the crashlog (thanks @Larme) it became obvious that I was trying to instantiate a view controller from storyboard with an identifier that didn't exist!
Just had to go in storyboard and put the right identifier on the view controller.